# eclipse content assist settings

Tags: eclipse, settings

How do I enable the eclipse setting that shows a dropdown list of available methods when typing code. For example if I type the name of an array list it should show me the available methods. I used to have that feature but somehow it got turned off.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check

> Windows > Preference > Java > Content assist

for content assist setting, and

> Windows > Preference > General > keys  (search 'content assist')

for key mapping

Path might be different if you are not using Helios (3.6)